# Check if client is using urllib2 to access php page

Tags: php

I want to make a php page that will know when the client is using the urllib2 python library.
Is it possible, and if so, how do i do it?

Comment: please provide info on what you already tried, and wxhat you define under "client", do you mean the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the user agent of the client using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to look for something like `Python-urllib/2.6`

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'urllib')) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

However, that's bound to be a lousy solution because someone who noticed they weren't getting "proper" scrapes from your site could simply change their user agent and resume with no difficulties.